# Rails: Reading a list of images from URLs and sending them to UI as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

In Rails controller, I wish to send image with some text to the front end in a hash. The front end would show each image along with its name.

```
def my_contoller
@my_hash = {
"abc"=>open("example.com?img1").read,
"pqr"=>open("example.com?img2").read,
"xyz"=>open("example.com?img3").read,
}
end
```

Front end (html.erb)

```
<center>
    <% @my_hash.each do |image_id,image|%>         
      <%="#{image_id}"%><%="#{image}"%>
    <% end %>
    </center>
```

I need the image_id to be available on front end to identify each image for further manipulations. How can I do this? Currently, the image_id is displayed fine but the image itself is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **HTML**, to display images on the web you need to use `<img>` tag with attribute `src`:

(*) `<img src="http://example.com?img1" alt="http://example.com?img1" />`

In **Rails**, you can use helper `image_tag` to do (*) with shorter syntax:

`image_tag 'http://example.com?img1'`

---

It means you don't need to read image files and display them on front-end, just pass `url` as the first argument with helper `image_tag`:

```
<% @my_hash.each do |image_id, image_url| %>         
  <%= image_tag image_url, data: { id: image_id } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put just image urls in the hash and then use `image_tag` to display them.

Backend:

```
def my_contoller
  @my_hash = {
    'abc' => 'http://example.com?img1',
    'pqr' => 'http://example.com?img2',
    'xyz' => 'http://example.com?img3'
  }
end
```

Frontend:

```
<center>
  <% @my_hash.each do |image_id, image_url| %>         
    <%= image_id %><%= image_tag(image_url) %>
  <% end %>
</center>
```